# How to set Image in imageview in fragment?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, camera

I used custom camera and i get image byte array data and pass in bundle another fragment but not display image in image view. my code below.

```
public class TakeCameraFragment extends Fragment {
    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

    protected static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 0;
    static String FilePAth = "";
    Button takePicture;
    static String base64string = "";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camerafragment,
                container, false);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(getActivity(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_fragment);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        takePicture = (Button) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicturefragment);
        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPictureframent);

            }
        });

        return rootView;

    }

    public boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
            releaseCamera();
        }
        return camera;
    }



    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraAppFragment");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());

        FilePAth = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_fragment_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg";

        Log.v("log", " FilePAth " + FilePAth);

        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_fragment_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }

    PictureCallback mPictureframent = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

                /*
                 * Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                 * returnIntent.putExtra("data", data); setResult(RESULT_OK,
                 * returnIntent); finish();
                 */

                Log.v("log_tag", "data :: " + data);
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                SetPictureImageFragment fm2 = new SetPictureImageFragment();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_Camera_fragment, fm2,
                        "HELLO");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putByteArray("position", data);
                fm2.setArguments(bundle);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * public void onBackPressed() { /*Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
     * returnIntent.putExtra("path", FilePAth); setResult(RESULT_OK,
     * returnIntent); finish(); };
     */

}
```

And i used takecamerafragment xml:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_Camera_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/conform" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePicturefragment"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview_fragment"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and i used second fragment ::

```
public class SetPictureImageFragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView img;
    Bundle bundle;
    byte[] path;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.create_store);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capturepicturefragment, null);

        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment");
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        path = bundle.getByteArray("position");

        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment ::: Path :: "+path);
        img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview_fragment_imageview);
        //img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(path, 0,path.length);


        img.setImageBitmap(b);
        img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);


        return view;
    }
}
```

I used SetPictureImageFragment xml:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative_CameraImageview_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/conform"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Conform" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakecanclePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="cancel" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview_fragment_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: i can't add this line because Rename fm2.

Comment: is this prints anything 
        Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment ::: Path :: "+path); or prints null

Comment: i print log and get byte array data in SetPictureImageFragment.

Comment: are you understand what i am asking..are you getting byte data ??]

Comment: in SetPictureImageFragment not in another fragment??

Comment: i don't know what r saying?

Comment: what it Log.v("log_tag","SetPictureImageFragment ::: Path :: "+path); prints??

Comment: i get print path:::  [B@421dc668

Comment: ok..you are getting byte array correctly..what about bitmap object..which is null or not..

Comment: ya i getting byte array and i convert byte array to bitmap

Comment: that means your layout has a problem..there is not enough space for imageview check once with dummy image from xml file..

Comment: i get  bitmap :: android.graphics.Bitmap@42108918

Comment: the code what you have written is working fine..may be the problem with the layout..

Comment: i set dummy image set image in imageview but new fragment not replace

Comment: if fragment not repalce oncrerateView never called..it is calling means your fragment is replaced..once check your layout..

Comment: One `Fragment` should never create another unless the second one is going to be a 'child' `Fragment` in which case you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. If the second `Fragment` isn't going to be a 'child' then simply pass the path of the image file to the parent `Activity` using a callback interface that is implemented by the `Activity` and have it then create the second `Fragment` and pass it the image file path. This is the correct way to do Fragment -> Fragment communication - inderectly via the `Activity`, not directly.

Comment: @Squonk i used getChildfragmentManager() but any changes.